# Как исправить ошибку при создание проекта в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, unity3d-android, ubuntu-unity

Пытаюсь создать проект. И что бы не исправлял, выбивает ошибка_
[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй удали этот java package, перенеси и установи его заново.